# How does a Repository delete removed Value Objects from the DB without ORM?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate, repository-pattern

Let's say an `Entity` is composed of multiple `ValueObjects`. For instance, a wanderer might leave a few footprints behind.

[image]

Imagine I load `Wanderer` from a repository and delete all footsteps north of the Canadian border. Since `Footstep` is a value object without identity (ID), how would the repository know which ones need to be deleted in the database? Is it supposed to delete all and write back only the ones held by the domain object it was given?

Similarly, consider a `Milestones` holding several `Issues` that can either be opened or closed. I should be able to modify any `Issue`'s state independent of whether it is grouped by a `Milestone` or not.

[image]

However, if I do close an `Issue`, the progress towards the `Milestone` (defined as the ratio of closed to total `Issues` contained) changes, and so does the representation of the `Milestone` which I'd like to update to reflect the new progress. Do Domain Events come into play here?

How are you supposed to handle such cases in the context of DDD?

Comment: Can you please fix the title of your question so that it asks the same question (in fewer words) that the body of your post asks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first case, you simply need to re-phrase "delete all footsteps north of the Canadian border" to "delete all footsteps where `y > latitude of border`" or something slightly more sophisticated. How would an ID for each `Footstep` even help with the above process? You are still left with figuring out which IDs correspond to a footstep north of the border.

For your second case, an `Issue` does not close itself. `Milestone` serves as a aggregate for a group of `Issue`. As such each `Milestone` closes (and opens) it's own issues. This makes sense in terms of flow anyway right? `Milestone.OpenIssue` seems to be the most declarative way to create a new `Issue`. In terms of storage, instead of your `"Issue"` table having some sort of `[status]` field (indicating "OPEN", "CLOSED", "PENDING", etc), you would instead store `[status]` on a join table between `"Milestone"` and `"Issue"`.

Slicing data *vertically* like this is an extremely powerful and important tactic when modeling a domain. It's important to identify your system in terms of *behavior*, not just data. In this case we have discovered, through minimal knowledge crunching, that an `Issue` does not have a `status` property!

Domain events are best-used to manage process, not synchronize state (e.g. `UserCreated` event is handled by your `EmailService` to send a welcome email). Once you begin to go down the road of trying to manage/sync state with events, your system will inevitably become quite complex and difficult to understand. The purpose of DDD is to create systems that are easy to *change*, and a system that cannot be understood cannot be changed.

The above isn't a *rule*. Of course there may be situations where you want state kept in sync (e.g. keeping denormalized read models up to date), but try your absolute best to avoid these kinds of gymnastics in your write model and always be looking for alternative strategies.

Comment: 1) The ID would help by being able to query for all footprints belonging to the wanderer which do not match the IDs I'm left with and deleting those. The repository has no notion of a condition on which to remove prints, all it gets is a domain object which it has to write back to the db. 2) Issues may very well exist on their own and have a status. They do not have to be grouped by a milestone.

Comment: @DoubleM 1) I don't see how an ID helps here. Either you can issue a query like `DELETE FROM [Footprint] WHERE x = ? AND y = ?` or you cannot delete any Footprints at all. At some point, your database has to be able to delete a row. How that row is identified is either through an ID (entity) or by the aggregate of it's values (value). The term `ValueObject` is not used to denote that the object has no identity, rather that it's identity is a directly result of it's value such that two `ValueObjects` are share the same identity if their values are equal.

Comment: @DoubleM 2) There is nothing in my answer to suggest that an `Issue` cannot exist on it's own. That said, allowing an `Issue` to change status outside a `Milestone` presents a problem. Either you manage an issue's `[status]` through an anonymous (or default) `Milestone` for those which don't have a specific one assigned, or you rethink your system. An `Entity` must be the single, unambiguous, and authoritative representation of it's state.

Comment: 1) The repository doesn't execute use-case relevant queries. It retrieves a wanderer and populates its collection of footprints, at a later point receives the modified wanderer object with footprints removed from the collection. See https://deviq.com/repository-pattern/ 2) I see your point, however no adequate solution to this problem.

Comment: @DoubleM 1) A `Repository` executes whatever queries are necessary to persist your domain. You are handcuffing yourself by adopting any other understanding. In any case, again, there is no reason an ID is necessary. If the identity of a `Footprint` is the combination of it's `x` and `y` properties your `Repository` will either, upon saving, has enough information to delete the appropriate `Footprints`. The process is exactly same whether the "where" clause uses `id` or `x AND y`.

Comment: @DoubleM 2) Like I mentioned, either adopt a default `Milestone` can be used to manage the `status` of all `Issues` that aren't explicitly tied to one. This `Milestone` needn't be stored. Or re-think your system. Is there a business reason why it *has* to work the way you are describing?

Comment: 1) ah so repositories are allowed to execute more business-logic related queries such as this one. No, 2) is just a hypothetical example for an entity that, in a way, contains other root entities which it shouldn't.

Comment: @DoubleM I think all queries could likely be classified as "business-logic related". An application is a means to express business logic. That said, I would try to separate the conduction of business logic (choosing your query parameters) from the actual execution of a query. For the coordinates example, the business logic decides the deletion criteria (`x` and `y` thresholds), but allows the `Repository` to figure out how to execute the deletion because the action is data source dependent.

Comment: @DoubleM As for your second example, you are correct. It just shouldn't exist in the way that you described. It's actually a great example highlighting the importance of domain modeling. I see questions like your second example all the time, and without fail, the question is asking for some "technical detail" about DDD/Architecture that alleviates the problem without questioning how it arose in the first place. The simple answer, in every case, is that the model itself must be looked at and possibly refactored to accommodate new rules. Continuous refactoring is an important discipline...

Comment: @DoubleM ... and a fundamental part of DDD. Often though, through knowledge crunching a more precise and fine-tuned understanding of a domain can be reached. Maybe an `Issue` doesn't need to exist on its own? Maybe a `Milestone` is only part of your read model, and eventual consistency is okay? Maybe an `Issue` has two `status` fields? Who knows. The important thing is to always be trying to figure it out.

Comment: Good points. I think the solution for 2) would be to have two separate root aggregates and update the milestone progress by listening to domain events - if done in the same transaction, it's even consistent. Else, it's an [integration event](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/02/07/domain-events-vs-integration-events-in-domain-driven-design-and-microservices-architectures/), and eventually consistent. What do you think?

Comment: @DoubleM Domain events are an option. But again, and I cannot stress this enough, it is incredibly easy (and tempting) to program yourself into a system with a large amount of interleaving by using domain events as a crutch to make up for poor design decisions. Such a system is, by definition, complex. One of the fundamental premises of DDD is to simplify systems by "making the implicit explicit". Domain events work *against* this idea by creating implicit coupling. So although they can/should be used when necessitated by a system, it's important to understand that they represent a "hack".